# MySQL Query wont SELECT id's above 19

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the code I am running. The strange thing is if I run the exact same query in PHPMyAdmin it runs perfectly.

But for any ID over 19 the `die()` clause activates but `mysql_error()` is empty and the number of rows returned are 0.

This is the strangest thing I have ever seen as if I drop the id to 1 through 19 it works.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE `id`='21'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($res)
{
    $ct = mysql_num_rows($res) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $ct;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your table structure ?

Comment: Why `die()` if `mysql_num_rows()` is 0? because essentially it's not an **error** at all so to speak. Secondly, it's strongly suggested you don't program with `mysql_*`

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated and being removed from the language in the near future. You shouldn't be using it. Consider PDO as an alternative.

Comment: Why are you doing `mysql_num_rows($res) or die(mysql_error())`?  Having a query return 0 rows is *not* an error.

Comment: did you try `id=21` without quotes?

Comment: The strange thing is that the query returns no results when run through PHP but always find 1 result in PHPMyAdmin which there is

Comment: the second mysql_error() will not generate the intended result because there is no error. Run the query in the native mysql console to confirm there are no ids higher than 19.

Comment: There are ids from 1 to 50. If I run the exact same query in PHPMyAdmin it returns 1 result. In PHP none. Why could that be?

Answer (score 4):

It looks and sounds like your "error" is on this line:

```
$ct = mysql_num_rows($res) or die(mysql_error());
```

With this, if `mysql_num_rows($res)` returns `0` (meaning "no results found matching your query"), your `or die(mysql_error())` portion will execute and, since there was no actual error, `mysql_error()` will return empty.

Try removing the `die()` part and change to something more user-friendly:

```
if($res) {
    $ct = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if ($ct === false) {
        // actual error
        die(mysql_error());
    } else if ($ct === 0) {
        // no results
        echo 'No results =[';
    } else {
        echo $ct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the two things is at work here.

#### 1) mysql_query($sql) could fail because of an error in your SQL query, and as suggested in these lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE `id`='21'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Not the case because the query is elementary and well constructed (albeit very unsafe, check PDO and parametrized queries).

#### 2) mysql_num_rows($res) is 0/null/false, and PHP script terminates, as suggested on these lines:

```
$ct = mysql_num_rows($res) or die(mysql_error());
```

Which is what happens in your scenario because your query doesn't return any results - Double check that there is something to find above id 19.

On a related note, it's bad practice to die() if no results are found.  Better to write a descriptive and informative message to the end user so that he can know what happened.